# How do I create a logical permutation expression automatically

Tags: permutation

How can I create a permutation automatically with logical expressions ?
For example (2 logical variables):

```
Not[a] && Not[b]
Not[a] && b
a && Not[b]
a && b
```

Comment: This should give you a start `Outer[(#1 ∧ #2) &, {a, Not[a]}, {b, Not[b]}]`

Comment: More generally, `vars = {a, b, c};
Outer[And, Sequence @@ ({#, Not@#} & /@ vars)] // Flatten`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Table[BooleanMinterms[{i}, #], {i, 0, 2^Length[#] - 1}] &[{a, b}]
(* {! a && ! b, ! a && b, a && ! b, a && b} *)

Table[BooleanMinterms[{i}, #], {i, 0, 2^Length[#] - 1}] &[{a, b, c}]
(* {! a && ! b && ! c, ! a && ! b && c, ! a && b && ! c, ! a && b && c, 
      a && ! b && ! c, a && ! b && c, a && b && ! c, a && b && c} *)
```

Also

```
Tuples[And @@ ({#, ! #} & /@ #)] &[{a, b}]
(* same output as above *)
Tuples[And @@ ({#, ! #} & /@ #)] &[{a, b, c}]
(* same output as above *)
```

Comment: Nice use of a non-`List` head in `Tuples`.